# In Sichuanese does 日本人 mean “fuck me”?

Tags: topolect, slang

I found a very interesting entry on Pleco:

> 日本人
>
> (Sichuanese expletive) fuck me (日 here means cào [肏])

I have never heard it but is this explanation correct? What is the etymology of this usage and when did it start to be used as such? Does this have any connection with the historical issue with Japan?

And also, in what kind of sentences is it used? Since Pleco doesn’t have any sample sentences, it would be highly appreciated if you could show me some.

Comment: That's awkward, on my Pleco,  日本人 shows up firstly as this curse then secondly as the overwhelmingly more common and known definition of a Japanese person...don't know if it's like this for all phones, but it's kinda horrible if a Japanese person is using Pleco to learn Chinese.

Comment: 日, as well as 操, 靠, is just a phonogram of **fuck**, not the **real** character of these characters. It's common in Sichuan and Shaanxi dialect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

**日** is the Sichuanese variant of 肏 and it can also be written: 㒲.

Here's an entry from《广安方言与民俗词典》:

> 日
>
> ri2
>
> 定义: 不文明语。指性交，交媾。常说成“搞”、“操”等词，民间骂人时，常说“～你妈”、“老狗～的”、“～妈的”、“～妈捣娘”、“～你先人板板”等，均指极粗野的谩骂。两人对骂时，也可谓“你有来言，我有对语”、“不假思索，配套成龙”、“骂人不打草稿”。例：甲：“日你妈！”乙：“吃得哟？！叫你妈回家多烧几把火嘛！”甲：“你妈卖屄！”乙：“你妈杀鸡我扯脚！”甲：“锤子！”乙：“锤子是你老汉儿！”
>
> 歇后语：“妓女罢工——抗日”，字面指拒绝性行为，引申为抗击日本军国主义行为。这些语言垃圾，虽然客观存在，但与文明社会格格不入，应当大力抵制与消除。

and an entry from 《南充方言词语考释》

> 肏
>
> ri2
>
> [rí(ʐɿ31)] 性交。动词。关汉卿 《包待制三勘蝴蝶梦》第三折： “两边 厢列着祗候人役，貌堂堂都是一伙洒肏娘的! 隔牢撺彻墙头去， 抵多少平空寻觅上天梯。(带云) 张千，(唱) 等我肏你奶奶歪 屄!”这是粗话。俗谓交媾，通常指男性主动对女性实施的性行 为。南充人说 “肏你妈”、“肏屄”、“老狗肏的”、“肏你妈卖屄”、 “肏你先人板板”等。《金瓶梅词话》第四回： “婆子骂道： ‘贼肏 娘的小猢猴，你敢高则声，大耳刮子，打出你去。’” 《红楼梦》 第十二回： “忽然灯光一闪，只见贾蔷举着个蜡台，照道： ‘谁在 这屋里呢?’ 只见炕上那人笑道： ‘瑞大叔要肏我呢!’”《歧路灯》 第六十四回： “我把狗吢儿使的往河北去了一个月，这老狗肏的 不得见他儿与他媳妇，每日只是在我庄上寻饭吃，晚上住在村头 牛王庙。”《大词典》例证为 《金瓶梅词话》，时代较晚。
>
> 又俗记音多作 “日”。《关汉卿戏剧词典》： “日，秽辞。交 媾。”①又加旁写作 “㒲”。 如关汉卿 《蝴蝶梦》三： “等我㒲你 奶奶歪屄。”
>
> 又记音讹误写成 “直”，《大词典》收 “直娘贼”，解释为 “詈语”，虽不准确，但符合文雅的要求。《水浒传》第五回： “那 大王却待挣扎，鲁智深把右手捏起拳头，骂一声 ‘直娘贼’! 连 耳根带脖子只一拳。”《水浒传》第十七回： “这直娘贼恨杀洒家， 吩咐寺里长老不许俺挂搭。”
>
> 注释
>
> ① 蓝立蓂. 关汉卿戏剧词典 [K]. 成都: 四川人民出版社,1993: 229.

**本人** just means me or myself the same as it does it MSM.

Out of speculation it probably arouse from a part hatred of Japanese and the fact that it sounds *almost* the same.

The proper pronunciation in Sichuanese (Pinyin) would be:

> 日·本人
>
> ri2 · ben3 ren2

with a slight pause in the middle.

It is just used as an exclamation: when you stub your toe, when you hit a pedestrian with your car, etc. the same as it's English counterpart.

Answer (score 6):

I am a native Sichuanese and have been living in Sichuan for decades.
I personally have never heard of anyone using this phrase and don't think I ever will.
Instead of a everyday phrase, this is more like a joke playing a pun on the character “日”(used both as a noun and a verb in Sichuanese) that you may find on some sites online. And I don't recommend using it in your daily conversations with anyone, because a)it sounds extremely awkward to me and b)it's very rude (and racist) to talk like this.
As for the slangy use of “日” as an exclamation, yeah, you can hear it here like every day. An equivalent in English would be "shit" or the F word. But still, it sounds rude. I would not recommend this usage to people you are not familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a fossilised phrase/word so it doesn't have a unique etymology. It can be decomposed into [日](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/7003/what-is-the-origin-of-%E6%97%A5-as-a-curse-word), 本 (*this, present*) and 人.

[本人](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA) is a formal way of saying *me* or *I*. Of course, this phrase is a vulgar slang and there's nothing formal about it.

Answer (score 1):

日 is used as a verb ,meaning fuck. 本人 means "me"，so  its meaning is fucking me! It's not polite! While 日本人 is used as a noun. It means Japanese persons

Answer (score 0):

No.

Take puns for fun, not seriously.

The only native way to interpret 日本人 is 日本-人, which means Japanese (people). I know a lot of people making fun using this pun by splitting 日本人 into 日-本人, which means fuck me, and it is understandable when thinking twice, but this is not the *normal* way to interpret it.